# SQL - Convert a String into a Text

Tags: java, sqlite

Sorry for bothering you again... I have a question about the SQLite database. I need to know how to transform a String into a Text so I can add this information to the table through a showInputDialog.

In the project, I've already converted a string into an integer without problems with this code:

```
String input = advice.showInputDialog("Insert number of the experiment:");
//String to integer
numExperiment = new Integer(input).intValue();

sql = "INSERT INTO Table VALUES ("+numExperiment+", "+column2+", "+column3+");";
```

But now in my database, in another table, I have this TEXT column and I need to insert data with the showInputDialog. I'm using the same setting for the first part... but how to proceed? I tried searching online but I can't find the method to do this o something similar.

```
String input = pGame.showInputDialog("Add a new game");

//Code that I don't know how to put

sql2 = "INSERT INTO Game VALUES ("+nGame+");";
```

Where nGame is the name of the column.

Thanks in advance for any advice or solution. Have a nice day.

Comment: Your generated sql string should be valid in the first place. Just open you sqlite debugging tool (or SQL standard for that mapper) and compare expected text formats with string that you generating. Second, you should never concatenate values into plain string, because that opens your program to SQL Injection attacks. Use bound variables instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String can be used directly in the sql statement with single quotes:

```
"INSERT INTO Game VALUES ('"+input+"');";
```

Comment: But don't ever do this if the input comes from outside your control ([obligatroy XKCD link](https://xkcd.com/327/)). Instead, search for "prepared statements".

Comment: @TripeHound yes - absolutely.